# how to know WHAT and WHEN the next cron job is?

Tags: cron

Is there a tool or a way to view the next scheduled job (in the system or at least at the user level) and its time, without looking into crontab (`crontab -l`)?

**Edit:** Imagine that there are 500 different cron jobs with repetitions. I need an "easy" way to know that the job A will be executed after 5 minutes from now.

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in solution, or a third-party, have-to-configure-and-setup web-based solution?

Comment: Actually either; any solution that shows the time and command of the next scheduled job; would be even better if it shows a list of the next jobs, e.g. for the next 24 hours. Otherwise, it is impractical to get this information from a crowded crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) for that, as well as adding new cron tasks and many other admin tasks. The Webmin module for viewing/editing cron tasks can be found under the System category. When you enter it you can see a table of all the [existing jobs on your system](http://www.webmin.com/screenshots/chapter10/figure1.gif).

Additionally, there is the possibility of parsing the crontab with a little code [in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321494/calculate-when-a-cron-job-will-be-executed-then-next-time), [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121374/calculate-cron-next-run-time-in-c-sharp), or in other language to answer your question.

Comment: more details please?

Comment: What would you like to know? What part of your question is left unanswered? :-)

Comment: Webmin isn't a clear answer.  You have suggested some random third party software for that, but that does not answer the asker's question.

Comment: As robot would say: "Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference."

Comment: I am happy to extend my answer, but would like to understand what the issue is here. The original question is "Is there a tool or a way to do X?", and I have provided the name of a tool to do X (and Y which is related to X), with a link to the tool itself. Why is that "not a clear answer"?

Comment: @sergut: I appreciate your answer, but at least for me it is unclear how to do X with Webmin. Imagine you have 500 different jobs which are highly overlapped with some repeated jobs. Does Webmin include a feature (e.g. a "view") to show that the job A will be executed after 5 minutes from now?